# Laravel search through relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, eloquent

Going straight to the point here.
I have a search functionality on my List of Items. However, I also want to search all items by category.

Here's what I have done so far.
I am really new to laravel and eloquent so please bear with me.

**Category Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('code', 30);
        $table->string('name');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Item Table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('code', 30);
        $table->string('name');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('items', function($table){
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    });
}
```

Here's my code:

```
public function search(){
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    if($q != ""){
        $items = Item::with('Category')
                    ->where ( 'name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' ) 
                    ->orWhere ( 'code', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
                    ->whereHas('Category', function($cat){
                        $cat->where('name', 'hardware');
                    })->paginate(1)->setPath('');

        $items = $items->appends ( array (
                    'q' => Input::get ( 'q' ) 
            ) );
    }else{
        $items = Item::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    }

    $softDeletesItems = Item::onlyTrashed()->get();
    return view('item.index', compact('items', 'softDeletesItems'));
}
```

is there a way for me to do a `orWHere('category.name', 'LIKE', '%'. $q .'%')`?

Comment: can you proviide both item and category table columns so we can check

Comment: hi @iCoders give me a second I will post it.

Comment: @iCoders can u check again?

Comment: ->whereHas('Category', function($query) use($q){
                       $query->where('name', 'hardware')->orWHere('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $q .'%')

Comment: @iCoders yes sir is there a way for me to do a `->orWhere ( 'categories.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )`?

Comment: ya updated my previous comment jush check

Comment: @iCoders still doesn't work though.

Comment: what error you are gettiing

Comment: @iCoders no errors but when I filter the items by category like `hardware` for example gives me 0 result

Comment: also remove with('Category') not requiored since you are using it in where

Comment: @iCoders I just removed the with('Category') still doesn't work..

Comment: can you check my updated answer below

Comment: @iCoders yes still doesn't work..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155473/discussion-between-icoders-and-sam-teng-wong).

Answer (score 2):

```
->whereHas('Category', function($query) use($q){

                       $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. $q .'%')

         })->paginate(1)->setPath('');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to achieve it.

```
    $items = Item
            ::join('categories', 'items.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->where ( 'items.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' ) 
            ->orWhere ( 'items.code', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )
            ->orWhere('categories.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->select('*')
            ->paginate(1)->setPath('');
```